# Смена url и передача его другим js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eсть меню, которое при нажатии меняет контент

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class="active" onclick="update_blogs()" id="home"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
   <li id="about" onclick="update_page(this)"><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
   <li id="contact" onclick="update_page(this)"><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
```

И функция, которая за это отвечает

```
function update_page(e) {
   let id = $(e).attr("id");

   $(".navbar-nav li").each(function () {
      $(".navbar-nav li").removeClass("active")
   });

   $(e).addClass("active");
   $.ajax({
      url: "php/update_page.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: ({id: id}),
      dataType: "html",
      success: function (data) {
         $(".content-page").html("");
         $(".content-page").hide();
         $(".content-page").html(data);
         $(".content-page").show(500);
         $(".close").show(500);

         let url = id;
         history.pushState("","", url)
      }
   })
}
```

Все хорошо работает, но надо чтобы ссылка менялась, и чтобы пользователь мог передать ее другому человеку и у того уже открывался контент, который хотел показать первый пользователь передавший ссылку

Comment: http://challenge.startnext.kz/day5  тестовый сайт

Comment: боюсь, что здесь еще нужно и серверную сторону менять

Comment: Хорошо как или что менять ?

Comment: Так вы же url-то меняете уже...

Comment: да но когда передашь ссылку она не правильно работает